# "Weekend day" or "holiday"?

Tags: word-choice, dates

For example, I want to say that there's *14 weekend days* in an interval between two dates, which means the sum of saturdays and sundays in that interval. How to say it correctly? What should I use instead of "weekend days" or it's correct?

**EDIT**:

It's an app, and user can choose, for example, 14 June 2015, which is Sunday, and 28 June 2015, which is Sunday again. Including first date, the sum of satudays and sundays in that interval will be 5. So I need one or two words that clearly descibe that instead of writing "sum of saturdays and sundays".

Here's what user currently sees on the screen. Take a look at "In this interval" section. Now it says "5 holidays", and that's what I'm talking about. Should I continue to use the word *holidays* or should I use another word(s)?

[image]

Comment: If a weekend is the end of the week, especially  the period from Friday night until the end of Sunday, you could say that in the  period there are 7 weekends.

Comment: @Josh61 The problem is, it's an app, and user can choose, for example, 14 June 2015, which is Sunday, and 28 June 2015, which is Sunday again. Including first date, the sum of satudays and sundays in that interval will be 5. So I need one or two words that clearly descibe that instead of writing "sum of saturdays and sundays".

Comment: @choster I've updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: There are still five 'Saturdays / Sundays' in your specified (inclusive) interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Weekend day** seems perfectly fine to me.  It's clear what it means.

**Holiday** would be wrong, because we don't describe normal weekend days as holidays - we reserve that term for particular days of special significance.  This is true in both British and American usage (even though other uses of the word **holiday** differ between the two).  See for example [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/holiday), which defines a holiday (in this sense) as "A day of festivity or recreation when no work is done", or [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holiday), which defines it as "a day marked by a general suspension of work in commemoration of an event ".

Incidentally, you haven't mentioned public holidays (also known as bank holidays in the UK).  If you want to include those, then it gets harder to find a concise expression.  **Non-working days**, as already suggested in comments on the OP, is the best I can come up with.